# Mod rewrite with Variables

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I am trying to use mod_rewrite with variables. But Sometimes not all variables will show up. If I don't place every variable in the URL it 404 error's out.

I Have this so far:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mypage\.([^/]*)?var1=([^/]*)&var2=([^/]*)&var3=([^/]*)$ /mypage.php?p=$1&$
```

But If i don't put all 4 of the variables it doesn't work. But I want the variables not to be in any certain order. Any Ideas?

My URL I want is http://myurl.com/mypage.home?var1=1&var2=2&var3=3&var4=4

Thank You

Comment: I don't understand what you're wanting to *rewrite* here. What URL format are you expecting on the request?

Comment: I am trying this http://myurl.com/mypage.var1?var2=2&var3=3&var4=4  where the variable "p" is the var1. then other variables after that as normal

Comment: What about `^mypage\.(.+)$ mypage.php?p=$1 [QSA]`

Comment: That works other than the 'p' variable is not showing the first letter. Example my page is a php page and I have it echo the "p" from _GET. When it does it cuts off the first letter

Comment: Works fine for me. It's probably matching more than once. Include the `L` flag, eg `[QSA,L]`

Comment: I Got it working by replacing .(.+) with ([^/]*)\  - Thank you. That really helped

Comment: The `L` flag should also work

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^mypage/([^/]*)$ mypage.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

worked